# Combine two PCI-e Power-Supply Pins

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, pci-express

Good evening, I have the following Problem:
I had for a long time a PC with a Nvidia GTX-480 Graphics-card.
Now since my old PC is slowly dying I bought a new one.

Now the new PC is planned to be used with an GTX 1150 /GTX 2050, however they may name it in the End. But since those aren't out yet, the old 480 has to take it's place for now in the new PC.

But the 480 has an 8 Pin + an 6 Pin connector which was fine with my old power supply, it had 3 14Pin PCIe Pins, but my new one has just two 8 Pins.

Now the question is, can I just use both the 8 Pins on my old 480 card even though they are two separated Pin sets or may that cause problem.

(This is just about the usage of two Pin Sets on one Hardware Part, I know how 8 and 6 Pin works)

Comment: what do you mean by separate pin sets?

Comment: I'm confused some because you say "*the 480 has an 8 Pin + an 6 Pin connector*" but then you ask "*can I just use both the 8 Pins on my old 480 card*"? I think the separate pin sets you refer is the PCIe power cable from the PSU that has 6-pin together and then two separate 2-pin that's optional from the same that connects together to make an 8-pin connector and that should work but check and compare the old and the new voltage outputs of the applicable PSU's from each motherboard to confirm. If the voltage output is the same then it should not be a problem.

Comment: The PSU has two 8 Pins for PCIe and the Card needs one 8 and one 6 Pin, so I use the old 6+2 Cables and just let one of the +2s unused.
The thing is, that the two 8 Pins on the PSU are made for two different PCIe devices and I use them both on one, so I wonder if that is ok or if that may cause some trouble.

Comment: I'm confused about the setup.  Would you please shorten the question for clarity, perhaps include some pictures of the connectors, and perhaps include a diagram?